# "cannot determine current directory" while building haskell

Tags: 11.10, installation, haskell

I'm trying to install haskell on ubuntu 11.10 and I'm following the instructions on this website: https://gist.github.com/1524859

But when I type `./configure` I get an error message saying:

```
checking for path to top of build tree... utils/ghc-pwd/dist/build/tmp/ghc-pwd: error while loading shared libraries: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
configure: error: cannot determine current directory
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure to install the dependencies first, `libgmp` seems to be among them. `sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev freeglut3 freeglut3-dev`

Comment: Okay I tried that and it's telling me the it is already the newest version. So I tried ./configure again and still the same error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm on 12.04 but where the current libgmp is libgmp.so.10, maybe the same as 11.10. Have you tried installing ghc & seeing if it suitable for your needs?

Comment: Okay fixed it with sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.0.1 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3

Comment: @TashaD: Providing the solution in the comment is nice, but even nicer is a self-answer (look it up on meta), to document for others, that there is an answer to the question, and mark it (√) as accepted answer, which signals, the problem is solved. Of course, now that Jorge wrote the answer, just accept it.

Comment: The solutions above work if you downloaded GHC for the right architecture, that is, if they don't work for you, re-check your download.

Answer (score 12):

I was able to solve this by just installing the right packages (no linking).

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3c2 freeglut3 freeglut3-dev -y
```

I'll note that I already had these dependencies installed:

```
make libssl-dev build-essential curl git-core
```

Comment: It was the libgmp3c2 package that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

Op fixed this with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.0.1 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64) with the slight change

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.0.5 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
```